# Gerar um calendário no R

Tags: r, calendar, lubridate

Necessito gerar um calendário com dias úteis no R, mas só do ano corrente. Estou utilizando o pacote `bizdays` para gerar os dias, mas não sei uma forma de selecionar somente o ano corrente.

Tentei utilizar da seguinte forma, mas não funcionou:

```
library(bizdays)
library(lubridate)

date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
data <- seq(as.Date(date), length = 2, by = "+12 months")[2]

dias_uteis <- bizseq(from = date, to = data, cal = "Brazil/ANBIMA")
dias_uteis <- subset(dias_uteis, dias_uteis %in% year(date))
```

Comment: Não entendi porque o comando `dias_uteis <- bizseq(from = date, to = data, cal = "Brazil/ANBIMA")` já não resolve este problema. Para mim, foi criada uma sequência de 251 datas (veja o resultado de `length(dias_uteis)`) que não possui vários dias, como é possível ver no resultado de `tail(dias_uteis)`: `"2020-12-23" "2020-12-24" "2020-12-28" "2020-12-29" "2020-12-30" "2020-12-31"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema precisa só da função `bizeq`. Esse código simplificado já resolve o seu problema:

```
library(bizdays)
dias_uteis = bizseq("2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "Brazil/ANBIMA")
```

Eu verifiquei no google e realmente existem [251 dias úteis](https://www.infomoney.com.br/economia/feriados-em-2020-ocupam-mais-dias-uteis-confira-as-datas/) em 2020.